# Nuget dependency not successful

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, blazor-client-side

Here is what I am doing:

[Searching for package Radzen.Blazor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuQQl.png)

[Installed the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baxrI.png)

[Waited for 5 mins, did a package restore. Still unable to reference it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2KRF.png)

Am I missing anything here ?

[Unable to refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc5VX.png)

Comment: What does 'unable to reference it' mean? The install seems to have been successful looking at your screenshots.

Comment: @MattWard , PFA screen .